# Issue "width" in css with Safari, how can i do it?

Tags: html, css, safari

My website is: kienanh.vn

When I'm testing cross browser I'm having trouble with Safari.

Any position I set: `width: abc px;` is not working in Safari? How do I fix it?

You can access my site with safari to see it!

#### My markup is:

```
<div id="wak">
<div id="quangcao1">  
<div id="slider1"></div> 
 <div id="slider2"><div> 
 <div id="slider3"><div>  
</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
#wak {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
#quangcao1 {
    height: 345px; // i don't set width for this elem
}
#slider1, #slider2, #slider3 {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    float: left;
    height: 335px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#slider1 {
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 490px;
}
#slider2, #slider3 {
    width: 240px;
}
```

**Now my issue is: convert px to em `http://pxtoem.com/` I'm trying do it. I think it work!**

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't set the dimensions of an inline element. Is the element in question `display:inline` ?

Comment: Also, this is going to be downvoted quite quickly. You need to be more specific about what element you're having trouble with and post the relevant html and CSS.

Comment: thank, i edited in my post.

Comment: Are you targeting all of your classes without a `.` in front?

Comment: my element use: id, so i've used # repare for .

Answer (score 0):

You should validate your HTML - http://validator.w3.org/ - and fix any errors found. For example, id's need to be unique. You have multiple  elements all with the id=wak. consider changing this to a class. This may resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank lukeocom but. i think in safari used elenment: Witdh: 100em;